# ASP.Net Web API POST to table with just a single identity column

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identity-column

I have a table with a single identity column, where I need to send a POST request and be able to retrieve the identity value that was generated.

My codes are as below:

```
// POST: api/XXXX
[ResponseType(typeof(MyFileDTO))]
public IHttpActionResult PostMyFile(MyFile myFile)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.MyFile.Add(myFile);
    db.SaveChanges();

    var dto = new MyFileDTO()
    {
        FileId = myFile.FileId
    };

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = myFile.FileId }, dto);
}
```

I am struggling a bit to test this POST call through Postman.

So, is there a proper way to create a POST api call similar to the situation described above where the only column is an identity?

Thanks.

** (Update) Additional Info:**
I am getting an error on the line:

```
db.MyFile.Add(myFile);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Where it is saying that value cannot be null, but I am not quite sure what value would need to be added here, as this is an identity column...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out a way to get around this.

Pretty much have the codes as below:

```
// POST: api/XXXX
[ResponseType(typeof(MyFileDTO))]
public IHttpActionResult PostMyFile(MyFile myFile)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.MyFile.Add(myFile);
    db.SaveChanges();

// Get the highest myFile value.
long maxMyFileId = db.MyFile.Max(p => p.MyFileId)

    var dto = new MyFileDTO()
    {
        FileId = maxMyFileId
    };

    return Ok(Dto);
}
```

Not sure if this is the proper way, but for now, it seems to resolve my issue of being able to obtain the column value.

Would appreciate any other answer if available.